# Attribution to a change in gross margin

Tags: calculus

I have tried to figure out this question for some time and would some input, while the underlying theme is business the question is based in pure math.

Basically lets say the following:

We have company A's sale in Year 1 and Year 2 for three products A, B and C.

Product A: 
1. Year 1 sale: 100 USD
2. Year 2 sale: 600 USD
Gross margin of 100%, both years

Product B:
1. Year 1 sale: 120 USD
2. Year 2 sale: 1000 USD
Gross margin of 10%, both years

Product C:
1. Year 1 sale: 50 USD
2. Year 2 sale: 300 USD
Gross margin of 80%, both years

How do I find the contribution to the difference in the total gross margin for each of the different products from year 1 to year 2? As far as I can tell this will likely be fairly complicated, but I am very much at a loss

Comment: What is the difference between gross margin and total gross margin?

Comment: Total gross margin is for all sale combined, other is for the individual products